# System.OutOfMemoryException with WCF during request

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-3.5

I have a server that is throwing an System.OutOfMemoryException, from what i can tell, during the transmission of data during a request.  From looking at this trace, is my assumption right?

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
  at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
  at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsServer(NetworkCredential credential, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel requiredImpersonationLevel)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeAcceptor.OnAcceptUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty& remoteSecurity)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamSecurityUpgradeAcceptorBase.AcceptUpgrade(Stream stream)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.InitialServerConnectionReader.UpgradeConnection(IConnection connection, StreamUpgradeAcceptor upgradeAcceptor, IDefaultCommunicationTimeouts defaultTimeouts)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader.ServerFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OpenAndEnsurePump()
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OpenAndEnsurePump(Object state)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.Invoke2()
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.OnSecurityContextCallback(Object o)
  at System.Security.SecurityContext.Run(SecurityContext securityContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.Invoke()
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.ProcessCallbacks()
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.CompletionCallback(Object state)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
  at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.Utility.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
  at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

I have maxArrayLength, and maxStringContentLength set really high in my config file.  Is it possible that one of these is extremely huge, and causing the channel to throw this error?  This is a .NET WCF service that is communicating locally through IPC with another process.

Comment: What is `really high`, you do know that there is a max limit.

Comment: How big is the payload you are sending?

Comment: Is this sporadic or does a specific message cause this?

Comment: im sending a report summary thats based on employee browsing, so it depends on how many employees the organization has.  The summary contains the urls of the pages visited as a generic Hashset, which is why maxArrayLength and maxStringContentLength popped in to my mind.  With querystrings, the hashset could contain the same page multiple times just with different query string values.  But other than that, i am kinda at a loss.  This particular customer is huge, so I wouldnt doubt if the summary is greater than 50MB.

Comment: @Conrad  It is sporadic, and even sometimes it seems to be thrown earlier in the trace (earliest i have seen it thrown at is ServerFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen)

Comment: another odd thing, is I have also a record of this error being thrown on Timer callbacks, although only a couple, compared to the WCF error.

Comment: what kind of environment is this dev, test, prod?

Comment: @Conrad  Its production.  I cant duplicate the errors in dev, or even on our live servers at our office.

Answer (score 3):

Given that this is a production issue and its happening in different places sporadically I'm guessing you're having a high memory utilization issue. I would obtain a Memory dump of the system and use WinDbg to see what's causing this.

You can use [proc dump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx)  or [Debug Diag](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&displaylang=en) to do this (but make sure you use the 32 or 64 bit one depending on which one you need).

If you've never done analysis on memory before (and its really not easy) then you might want to take a look at [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/15/net-debugging-demos-lab-3-memory.aspx)